# Prometheus/BlackBox Exporter probe_success 0 but service still running

Tags: prometheus

I'm currently utilizing Prometheus with Blackbox Exporter for monitoring our services. However, I've encountered an issue where one of our external services is showing probe_success as 0, despite being accessible when tested with curl.

***All my other services are being monitored correctly.***

I would appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this discrepancy.
Thank you.
prometheus config

```
  - job_name: 'ExternalPartners_ICMP'
    scrape_interval: 15s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - https://*/*.asmx  #GazProm
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

blackbox config

```
http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      valid_http_versions:
      - HTTP/1.1
      - HTTP/2
      - HTTP/2.0
      valid_status_codes: [200]
      method: GET
      no_follow_redirects: false
      fail_if_ssl: false
      fail_if_not_ssl: true
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
      ip_protocol_fallback: true
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: What is shown in blackbox when you [query it directly](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#checking-the-results) with `&debug=true`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe `tls_config` setting needs to be set

```
 scheme: https
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @mikequentel. I appreciate your assistance, I've tried adding the configuration both in blackbox.yml and prometheus.yml, but it doesn't seem to be working.